# Can't make UIAlertView call delegation methods - Deployment target iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on XCode7 and on this project I am working on, UIAlertview is working fine.
I set up a cocoa-touch file, defined a new class inheriting from `NSobject`,

**`NSVerifier.h`**

```
@interface NSVerifier : NSObject<UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
..    
}
```

and inside the implementation I have:

**`NSVerifier.m`**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)aView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
//Breakpoint here
..
}

-(void)show{
        UIAlertView* t = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"testing" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
        [t show];
}
```

inside **`viewDidAppear`**:

```
NSSVerifier* iVerifier = [[NSVerifier alloc] init];
[iVerifier show];
```

I was trying all day to make that breakpoint stop when I press the **`ok`** button, but the breakpoint was never reached.

On the other hand...

I have another project that was made during iOS7 times, and I imported this class in. It works there...
When I put the delegation methods I got a warning the `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS9, and on which device I am debugging (iOS9), But since the deployment target on both devices is iOS7, should this not work still?

Comment: Are you the instance of `NSVerifier` alive?

Comment: Don't use the prefix NS. I'd suggest using your own initials. `JXVerifier` instead. If Apple ever releases a class in the future called `NSVerifier` your code will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the alert delegate to be self:

```
t.delegate = self;
```

Try that?

**Update:** And make sure where your NSVerifier is created it has a strong reference so the UIAlertView delegate doesn't get dropped later once the UIAlertView is shown. E.g in your ViewController create iVerifier in your .h:

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSVerifier *iVerifier;

Just another thought

Comment: delegate is set on init

Comment: Any luck with making it a strong reference?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't retain **iVerifier** and it gets deallocated causing UIAlertView's delegate property to be nil.

Following should help:

```
// In interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSSVerifier* iVerifier;

// In implementation

NSSVerifier* iVerifier = [[NSVerifier alloc] init];
self.iVerifier = iVerifier;
[iVefirier show];
```

Comment: Thats what I suggested

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it in original answer. Race condition :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `iVerifier` is released after the code go out `viewDidAppear`.

Please try: handle the `iVerifier` by a property with strong reference.